# C - How to assign multiple values to the same key in a hashmap?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

As a novice programmer I started reading through [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) to learn more about `pointers` and `structs`.

I am currently learning about hashmaps in C. Following the example in the book, I created my own hashmap to hold key-value pairs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 100
#define HASHSIZE 101

static struct map *hashtab[HASHSIZE]; /* pointer table */
unsigned hash(char *);  /* hashing function: form hash value for string s. used by both lookup and install*/
char *strdup(char *);

struct map {        /* creating a map structure */
    struct map *next;
    char *KEY;          /* KEY - pointer to a char - member of nlist*/
    char *object1;      /* object - pointer to a char - member of nlist*/
};

/* lookup function takes a pointer to char - s as an argument and returns a pointer to map structure */
struct map *lookup(char *s) {
    struct map *np;

    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next) {
        if (strcmp(s, np->KEY) == 0) {
            return np;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* install function takes a pointer to a char - KEY, object and returns a pointer to map structure */
struct map *install(char *KEY, char *object1) {
    /* install: put (name, defn) in */
    /* Install uses lookup to determine whether the KEY being installed
       is already present. Proceeds to create a new entry or update*/
    struct map *np;
    unsigned hashval;

    if ((np = lookup(KEY)) == NULL) {
        np = (struct map *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->KEY = strdup(KEY)) == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        hashval = hash(KEY);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    }
    else {
        free((void *)np->object1);
    }
    if ((np->object1 = strdup(object1)) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return np;
}
```

I then assign values to keys as follows:

```
int main(void) {

    struct map *table[4] = {
        (install("key1", "value1")),
        (install("key2", "value2")),
        (install("key3", "value3")),
        (install("key4", "value4"))
    };

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%s->%s\n", table[i]->KEY, table[i]->object);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code above works well, I am able to assign `value1`, ... , `value4` to `key1`, ... ,`key4` respectively. However, this does not allow me to assign multiple values to the same key.

Let's say I read the following from a text file:

```
key1 9000 600 Test1
key2 2000 600 Test2
key3 3000 120 Test3
key4 4000 120 Test4
.
.
key10 1000 560 Test10
```

I want to be able to store each key and assign multiple values to it. Since  the number of columns is fixed, maybe I could have a structure that represents a row and put that into the map.

To do so, `install` needs to be modified to be able to add multiple values for the same key. Since the keys are unique, `lookup` and `uninstall` (function I created to remove keys) should remain unchanged.

The code above works perfectly, however I am looking for a general solution to add multiple values to the same keys.

How should I proceed to be able to call:

```
struct map *table[4] = {
    (install("key1", "9000" ,"600", "Test1")),   //key, object1, object2, object3
    (install("key2", "2000" ,"600", "Test2")),
    (install("key3", "3000" ,"120", "Test3")),
    (install("key4", "4000" ,"120", "Test4"))
};
```

Another idea would be:

```
/* key points to this struct */
struct Value {
    int i;
    int k;
    char *c;
};

typedef struct map {        /* creating a map structure */
    struct map *next;
    char *KEY;
    struct Value value;  /* place multiple values inside a struct*/
};
```

and here is where I am getting stuck:

```
struct map *insert(char *KEY, struct *Value) {
    struct map *np;
    unsigned hashval;

    if ((np = lookup(KEY)) == NULL) {
        np = (struct map *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->KEY = strdup(KEY)) == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        hashval = hash(KEY);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    }
    else {
        free((struct Value*)np->value); //type cast cannot convert from 'Value' to 'Value*'

    }
    if ((np->Value = strdup(Value)) == NULL) { //map has no field value
        return NULL;
    }

    return np;
}
```

I searched through the following questions, however was unable to extract the relevant information on how to implement this in C.

[Hashmaps having multiple keys with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058968/hashmaps-having-multiple-keys-with-multiple-values)

[How can I assign multiple values to a hash key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687529/how-can-i-assign-multiple-values-to-a-hash-key)

[HashMap with multiple valued keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509471/hashmap-with-multiple-valued-keys)

How can I implement a hashmap which accepts multiple values assigned to the same key?

---

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, the structure I am using may not be actuallly a hashmap but a linked list. However the [book](http://www.dipmat.univpm.it/~demeio/public/the_c_programming_language_2.pdf) specifically says that page 144 is a hashmap.

Comment: Hint: when inserting, treat any duplicate keys exactly as you treat collisions.

Comment: Thanks will look into it. Also, why is Implementing a hashmap with multiple values pointing to the same key considered broad? How can I improve my question?

Comment: Your structure here is not actually a hash nap, it is a linked list. There are a number of ways you could go to accomplish your objective, but the traditional would be: actually implement a hash nap, and then when you have a key collision, implement a linked list of objects under that key.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I fail to understand why I am expecting key collisions with such a small number of keys as in my example (10). Also why does the book I am referring to call the structure a hasmap? That is what confused me.

Comment: If you want multiple values per key, you could add  `val1 ... val4` to the map's structure members, or use an array of values. Or even a second type of linked list or hashtable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So instead of passing another struct `Value` to hold `val1 ... val4`, I place these directly inside the map structure.

Comment: An actual hash table or hash map associates each key with exactly *one* value.  How else could one reasonably retrieve objects from such a data structure?  But the one value can be of whatever type you choose, and in particular, and can be a type that can contain multiple other objects, such as a linked list (or the head of one).

Comment: @JohnBollinger A reasonable way to retrieve values from a *multimap* is to have `get_first(multimap, key)->iterator` and `get_next(iterator)->iterator` methods. This is embodied in the C++ interface of `std::unordered_multimap` for example. There's no need to specify a set or a list or any other concrete collection as the value type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best possible solution, but thanks to the above comments I got something working. I am declaring multiple values as pointers to `char`. Please let me know if I can improve this.

I am yet to implement collision correction.

```
struct map {        /* creating a map structure */
    struct map *next;
    char *KEY;
    char *value1;
    char *value2;
    char *value3;
};
```

I then pass these to the insert function.

```
struct map *insert(char *KEY, char *value1, char *value2, char *value3) {
    /* install: put (name, defn) in */
    /* Install uses lookup to determine whether the KEY being installed
       is already present. Proceeds to create a new entry or update*/
    struct map *np;
    unsigned hashval;

    if ((np = lookup(KEY)) == NULL) {
        np = (struct map *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->KEY = strdup(KEY)) == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        hashval = hash(KEY);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    }
    else {
        free((void *)np->value1); //type cast cannot convert from 'Value' to 'Value*'
        free((void *)np->value2);
        free((void *)np->value3);
    }
    if ((np->time = strdup(value1)) == NULL) { //map has no field value
        return NULL;
    }
    if ((np->description = strdup(value2)) == NULL) { //map has no field value
        return NULL;
    }
    if ((np->duration = strdup(value3)) == NULL) { //map has no field value
        return NULL;
    }

    return np;
}
```

Printing these will give the key pointing the the four values.

`key1->value1 value2 value3`